# User registration issue with google firebase using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, openssl

I use this code to register user to Google firebase.

Language: **Node JS**

Authentication: **Google Firebase**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
var serviceAccount = require("firebase.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

User get registered successfully, But randomly I get this error as shown in below screenshot.

Error message: "Error while making request: write EPROTO 140388551321408: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252\n. Error code: EPROTO".

Open SSL version is: **OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016**

[image]

Comment: Please include the error message in plain text too, so that it can be found through search.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Update my question and added Error in Text. Thanks